# Which configuration of IDE/editors/plugin is best suited for developing Laszlo applications?

Tags: openlaszlo, laszlo

I'm exploring the [Laszlo](http://www.openlaszlo.org) technology, which configuration of IDE/plugins/editors do you would suggest to me to use with Laszlo projects?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse with the [Spket IDE](http://www.spket.com/) plugin

Answer (score -3):

I don't code Laszlo, but I bet someone would say emacs.